# What is this plane seen in the Falcon Crest TV series?

Tags: aircraft-identification

[image]

Does anyone recognize the make and model of this small plane?  It was used in episode 154 <6.27> "Chain Reaction" of the 1980's TV show "Falcon Crest".  I'm working on a database for the show's picture planes and I am missing the identification of this aircraft and two more planes. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Obviously a Cessna.  Exact model (172, 175, 177, 182) depends on details I'm not familiar enough with to call.

Comment: Looks like a [Cessna 210](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cessna_210) to me.

Comment: If the episode ever shows the tail number, you can google it and it will take you to the FAA records for the airframe showing you manufacturer, model, owner, etc. ie N12345

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @mikem This suggestion works for day-to-day photos, but may not always work for movies. Movies may use fake or "recycled" registrations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a [Cessna 210 Centurion II](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cessna_210)
.

The Cessna 210 models K, L, M, N and R have the windows shaped like the one shown in the picture from Falcon Crest. If it has a two-bladed propeller, it is a model K, the others have three-bladed props.

The picture below is a Cessna 210M.

[image: Cessna 210M Centurion II]
source: [www.airhistory.net](https://www.airhistory.net/photo/45226/VH-EJA), photo copyright: Phil Vabre

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your explanation is very helpful.